# Need you with SQL subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to help with MySQL Subquery.

I have got 1 table, where I am inserting data that I select from second table, but I need make exception for those ids that are written in 3rd table...

How can I do it?

I am inserting into main table from second using this query:

```
INSERT INTO player_ranking (SELECT @i:=@i+1 as rank, t.id FROM player t, 
(SELECT @i:=0) AS temp ORDER BY level DESC, exp DESC LIMIT 3)
```

But I need to make there condition like "WHERE id from that table does not equal id from 3rd table...

Could you help me, please?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? give tables as texts!!! and expllain!!!!!!!!!

Comment: (SELECT @i:=0) AS temp ???]

Answer (score 1):

To exclude records that are present in the third table, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` on that table with a `WHERE` clause that selects only non-matching records.

The below query assumes that the third table is called `table3`, and has a column named `id` that references column `id` in table `player`.

Like :

```
INSERT INTO player_ranking (
    SELECT @i:=@i+1 as rank, t.id 
    FROM player AS t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i:=0) AS temp
    LEFT JOIN table3 on t.id = table3.id
    WHERE table3.id IS NULL
    ORDER BY level DESC, exp DESC 
    LIMIT 3
)
```

Comment: that temp sub-query is just a trick to initialize the variables inside the Sql. Because if one would run another Sql before it that uses the same variables, then those variables would have the final values from the previous sql.

Comment: @LukStorms : ok, thanks for explanation... I updated my answer accordingly (used a `CROSS JOIN` for that subquery)